# Why is Windows 8.1 Update and its prerequisites considered "not required" by SCCM?

Tags: sccm, windows-8.1, sccm-2012-r2

I have a fresh (<2 months old) installation of a standalone SCCM 2012R2 server.  I have installed the software update point and WSUS on the same server.  SCCM and WSUS are synchronizing and some updates are deploying to freshly-deployed Windows 8.1 test clients.

The problem is this: The [troubled](http://www.infoworld.com/article/2608069/microsoft-windows/microsoft-reissues-botched-windows-8-1-update-kb-2919355.html) [Windows 8.1 Update](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-ca/windows-8/install-latest-update-windows-8-1) [KB2919355](http://www.microsoft.com/en-ca/download/details.aspx?id=42335) does not deploy automatically.

SCCM seems to consider Windows 8.1 Update (KB2919355) "Not Required" despite that all 3 of the assets are Windows 8.1 clients:

[image]

I am aware that [KB2919442](https://support.microsoft.com/kb/2919442) is a prerequisite for KB2919355.  However, WSUS reports the prerequisite KB291442 as superceded by KB2989647:

[image]

KB2975061, KB2969339, and KB2904440 are each also superceded by KB2989647.

As it turns out, the update that supercedes the prerequisite to Windows 8.1 Update, KB2989647, is [also considered "not required" by SCCM](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mCUE7.png).

Which leaves me with the following questions:

1. Why is Windows 8.1 Update and its prerequisites considered "not required" by SCCM?
2. How does SCCM decide which updates are "required" and which are "not required"?
3. Is there a way to override updates from "not required" to "required"?

Answer (score 2):

The solution ([see this technet thread](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/d6697968-3fb8-4386-9128-90156709a6e9/deploying-windows-81-update-1-kb2919355?forum=configmanagersecurity)) is to *manually* download and install the superseded prerequisite patch KB2919442. Once KB2919442 is installed, all subsequent updates should install through the usual SCCM Software Update deployment method.

To streamline this workaround a bit more, I packaged the prerequisite patch KB2919442 as an SCCM application and made it a required deployment. This strategy seems to be working and freshly-deployed Windows 8.1 RTM machines seem to eventually end up with current patches without intervention.